htop 3.3 not showing process cpu percentage in tree mode
I was using htop for a long time, but i upgraded to 3.3 today.
It's not showing cpu percentage for a process collapsed in tree mode.
See the cpu usage shown in list mode and then no cpu usage being shown in tree collapsed mode.
CPU usage shown in list mode-

No CPU usage shown in tree mode (see the processors being consumed at the top) -

The old htop ver 3.0.5 had this perfect. It shows the overall process usage in tree mode -

the process percentage for the threads in htop ver 3.0.5 -


Your post is actually making very little sense. Both screenshots are from "Tree view" (none is in list view), and one of them have the branch collapsed. But you're right htop does not "consolidate" CPU usage for a branch, and it never did. If you would suggest a new feature to htop, please suggest it on the official Github page.

@ArturMeinild i added the htop ver 3.0.5 screenshots for the problem definition.

No matter how you cut it, bug reports should go to the htop Github page - not here. We can't fix software bugs for you.

I'm also using htop 3.3, and I can't reproduce this. Also there are several factors as to why you don't see the same CPU usage:

The process you have highlighted is not the same (the PID is different)
You show all the subprocesses (which just clutters the view IMHO)
You have collapsed the branch in the tree view (expand/collapse with + and - keys)

If you hightlight the same PID in both views, you should see the same CPU usage.
Proof:



PID is the same for the parent VLC - 16767

Please see my comment on your post. This is not even a bug, but it seems you would like to suggest a new feature (consolidated CPU usage for a collapsed branch). Unfortunately, Ask Ubuntu is not the place to discuss neither bugs nor feature requests for Ubuntu software.
